# Basic Java Swing Calculator

Tags: java, beginner, swing, calculator

I am new to Java Swing and have decided to create a calculator to learn some of the basic. I would like someone to look over my code to see if they can give me any improvements.

I have 6 classes and 2 interfaces. I have chosen to split the communication of both operators and digits. The mainframe is the controller and actually creates the objects. The other classes are the different components.

`MainFrame` (creates all objects):

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private FormArea formpanel;
    private OutputArea outputText;
    private WorkoutExpression workingOutMathExpression;
    private static String mathmaticalExpression = "";

    public MainFrame() {
        super("Calculator");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        formpanel = new FormArea();
        outputText = new OutputArea();
        workingOutMathExpression = new WorkoutExpression();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        formpanel.setStringListener(new DigitListener() {

            public void StringEmmiter(String text) {
                outputText.addText(text);
                mathmaticalExpression = mathmaticalExpression + text;
                //System.out.println(mathmaticalExpression);
                WorkoutExpression.setMathExpression(mathmaticalExpression);

            }
        });

        formpanel.setOperatorListener(new MathOperatorListener() {

            public void OperatorEmitter(String text2a) {
                if (text2a.equals("CLEAR")) {
                    outputText.refreshTextArea();
                    mathmaticalExpression = "";
                    workingOutMathExpression.resetMathExpression();

                } else if (text2a.equals("CLEAR") == false) {
                    outputText.addText(text2a);

                    if (text2a.equals("=")) {
                        try {
                            outputText.addText(workingOutMathExpression.getCalculationOfExpression());
                        } catch (ScriptException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        mathmaticalExpression = mathmaticalExpression + text2a;
                        //System.out.println(mathmaticalExpression);
                        WorkoutExpression.setMathExpression(mathmaticalExpression);
                    }

                }

            }
        });

        add(formpanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(outputText, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

Formpanel is the panel which contains all the buttons:

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FormArea extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private ButtonTemplate No1;
    private ButtonTemplate No2;
    private ButtonTemplate No3;
    private ButtonTemplate No4;
    private ButtonTemplate No5;
    private ButtonTemplate No6;
    private ButtonTemplate No7;
    private ButtonTemplate No8;
    private ButtonTemplate No9;
    private ButtonTemplate No0;
    private ButtonTemplate addition;
    private ButtonTemplate substraction;
    private ButtonTemplate division;
    private ButtonTemplate total;
    private ButtonTemplate multiplication;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private ButtonTemplate decimalPoint;

    private DigitListener digitListener;
    private MathOperatorListener operatorListener;

    public FormArea() {
        // SetSize
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
        // Create all Objects
        No1 = new ButtonTemplate("1");
        No2 = new ButtonTemplate("2");
        No3 = new ButtonTemplate("3");
        No4 = new ButtonTemplate("4");
        No5 = new ButtonTemplate("5");
        No6 = new ButtonTemplate("6");
        No7 = new ButtonTemplate("7");
        No8 = new ButtonTemplate("8");
        No9 = new ButtonTemplate("9");
        No0 = new ButtonTemplate("0");
        addition = new ButtonTemplate("+");
        substraction = new ButtonTemplate("-");
        division = new ButtonTemplate("/");
        total = new ButtonTemplate("=");
        multiplication = new ButtonTemplate("*");
        clearButton = new JButton("CLEAR");
        decimalPoint = new ButtonTemplate(".");

        clearButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 60));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Layout

        // Column 1
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No1, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No4, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No7, gc);

        // Column 2
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No2, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No5, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No8, gc);

        // Column3
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No3, gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No6, gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No9, gc);

        // Operators

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(addition, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(No0, gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(substraction, gc);

        // Operator 2

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(division, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(multiplication, gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(total, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 5;
        add(clearButton, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        gc.weightx = 0.1;
        gc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(decimalPoint, gc);


        // ActionButton
        No1.addActionListener(this);
        No2.addActionListener(this);
        No3.addActionListener(this);
        No4.addActionListener(this);
        No5.addActionListener(this);
        No6.addActionListener(this);
        No7.addActionListener(this);
        No8.addActionListener(this);
        No9.addActionListener(this);
        No0.addActionListener(this);

        ArrayList<ButtonTemplate> operatorsArrayList = 
        new ArrayList<ButtonTemplate>(Arrays.asList(iterateThroughOperators()));

        for (ButtonTemplate btn : operatorsArrayList) {
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ButtonTemplate source1 = (ButtonTemplate) e.getSource();

                    if (source1 == btn) {
                        operatorListener.OperatorEmitter(btn.getText());

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton s1 =  (JButton) e.getSource();

                operatorListener.OperatorEmitter(s1.getText());

            }
        });

    }

    public void setStringListener(DigitListener digitlistener) {
        this.digitListener = digitlistener;
    }

    public void setOperatorListener(MathOperatorListener operatorListener) {
        this.operatorListener = operatorListener;
    }

    public ButtonTemplate[] iterateThroughButton() {
        ButtonTemplate btn[] = { No1, No2, No3, No4, No5, No6, No7, No8, No9, No0 };
        return btn;
    }

    public ButtonTemplate[] iterateThroughOperators() {
        ButtonTemplate operatorBtn[] = { addition, substraction, division, total, multiplication,decimalPoint
                };

        return operatorBtn;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();

        for (ButtonTemplate SingleButton : iterateThroughButton()) {
            if (source == SingleButton) {

                digitListener.StringEmmiter(SingleButton.getText());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Button Template is just a standard button with a specified size:

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ButtonTemplate extends JButton{
    private String nameOfTheButton;

    public ButtonTemplate(String nameOfButton){
        this.nameOfTheButton = nameOfButton;
        this.setText(nameOfTheButton);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,50));

    }


}
```

`DigitListener` listens for the digits and sends them to the mainframe:

```
package calculator;

public interface DigitListener {
    public void StringEmmiter(String text1);
}
```

Operator listener listens to the operators and sends them to the mainframe:

```
package calculator;

public interface MathOperatorListener {
    public void OperatorEmitter(String text2);

}
```

`MathExpression` works out the mathematical expression using scriptengine:

```
package calculator;

import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class WorkoutExpression {

    private static String mathExpression;

    public static void setMathExpression(String mathExpression) {
        WorkoutExpression.mathExpression = mathExpression;
    }
    public String getCalculationOfExpression() throws ScriptException{
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        return  engine.eval(mathExpression).toString();

    }
    public void resetMathExpression(){
        mathExpression = "0";
    }



}
```

Output area is whether the calculation is displayed:

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class OutputArea extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textarea;

    public OutputArea() {
        textarea = new JTextArea();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JScrollPane(textarea));
    }

    public void addText(String text){
        textarea.append(text);
    }
    public void refreshTextArea(){
        textarea.setText(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! A Github link to your project, while not needed, would make testing easier for the reviewers allowing better quality reviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Arrays

At a glance, your creating and instantiating the `ButtonTemplate` objects could be done as an array.

e.g.

`private ButtonTemplate[] buttons = new ButtonTemplate[10];`

It would allow you to use a simple loop to instantiate, and add the ActionListener, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i] = new ButtonTemplate(Integer.toString(i));
  buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
}
```

### Employ Lambda Expressions

If you have access to Java 8, You can use [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to simply the code where you use [Functional Interfaces](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/), e.g.

instead of:

> ```
> btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>                     ButtonTemplate source1 = (ButtonTemplate) e.getSource();
>
>                    if (source1 == btn) {
>                        operatorListener.OperatorEmitter(btn.getText());
>                     }
>                }
>             });
> ```

You can simply write:

```
btn.addActionListener(e -> {
  if ((ButtonTemplate)e.getSource() == btn) {
    operatorListener.OperatorEmitter(btn.getText());
  }
});
```

I also use `e.getSource()` directly here rather than storing it as a variable since we're only doing one thing with it anyway, but feel free to use it your way if you find it makes it more understandable/readable.

Read up on what I linked, but just as an additional example, your `MathOperatorListener` is a functional interface. So this section where you call `setOperatorListener`

> ```
> formpanel.setOperatorListener(new MathOperatorListener() {
>             public void OperatorEmitter(String text2a) {
> ```

Can be replaced with:

```
formpanel.setOperatorListener(e -> {
  // content
});
```

The e is just a variable used to refer to the text2a that is passed. You can name it anything. Same deal of course for your `DigitListener` interface. You may start using the @FunctionalInterface annotation so the compiler would check and confirm for you, albeit Functional Interfaces are easily identifiable since they only have a single method).